# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list error how to fix?

Tags: python, random, tkinter

I have some code where it goes through a for loop and should give me and output of 9 rows and 9 columns of buttons in a tkinter window. These buttons should have a random number in them ranging from 1 to 9. But I do not want the same number in the same column and row to be the same.

To acomplish this I have tried .pop[] and .remove() and del but none have properly worked. I get the error row1.remove("4")
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list. And there is 2 of the same number in the same row when I tried to remove that number. Can somebody please help?

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
row1 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
col1 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
button = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
random.shuffle(button)
root = tk.Tk()
i = 0
for x in range(9):
    for y in range(9):
        number = random.choice(button)
        btn = tk.Button(text=number, bg="white", activebackground="black", 
width=2)
        btn.grid(row=y, column=x)
        i += 1
        print(number)
        if number == "1":
            row1.remove("1")
            col1.remove("1")
        elif number == "2":
            row1.remove("2")
            col1.remove("2")
```

The elif goes all the way down to the number 9 by the way. I just didnt want all of it in here.

I expect the output to be a 9 x 9 grid all containing a random number ranging from 1 to 9 and none of the numbers to be the same in a row and column.

Comment: `random.choice(button)` can and eventually will choose the same element twice.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to rethink the logic. You are far from your goal.

Comment: @Goyo even if i remove it  from that list?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I have two suggestions. First, try writing your number-generation logic independently of tkinter. Write a function that assigns numbers to a 9x9 list-of-lists, and then use that data structure to create your buttons afterwards. Second, your problem is very similar to the game Sudoku, which fortunately has many existing open-source Python implementations. Try searching for "python sudoku generator" to get an idea of how grids like these are usually generated. You just need to cut out the parts of those solutions that require uniqueness in each 3x3 section.

Comment: You are not removing anything from `button`.

Comment: And if you remove from that list, you are going out of numbers. You need 81 numbers for your grid, and there are only 9 numbers in `button`.

Comment: @Kevin that is what i am trying to create thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Below script with inline code explains a lot. As your matrix is 9x9 I used rows*columns = 81 because you can then ID them all. If only 9 values you get still some doubles. Easily to adjust with adjusting `unique_value`. Enjoy simplicity ;P

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

rows       = 9
columns    = 9

unique_IDs = 9   # unique IDs per row. If value below e.g. rows 
                 # then backup button list is created to prevent
                 # an empty list below. Value larger than zero.

root = tk.Tk()
i = 0

# if matrix == unique IDs the amount (rows * columns)IDs is created.
if rows * columns == unique_IDs:

    # if unique IDs are smaller than row values below code 
    # compensates for it by taking total positions in rows as base.                          
    if unique_IDs < rows:
        button = [*range(1, ((rows) + 1))]
    else:
        button = [*range(1, ((unique_IDs) + 1))]

    random.shuffle(button)

    print ('random : %s' % button)   # checks if list random is truly random.

for x in range(rows):

    # if matrix != unique IDs the amount of unique_IDs is created.
    if (rows * columns) != unique_IDs:                      
        button        = [*range(1, ((unique_IDs) + 1))]

        random.shuffle(button)

        print ('random : %s' % button)   # checks if list random is truly random.

    for y in range(columns):

        # number = random.choice(button) # twice the shuffle dance? Nah!
        number = button.pop(0)           # just keep popping the soda at first number 
                                         # from the randomized button order list
                                         # while it gets smaller and smaller.

        btn = tk.Button(text=number, bg="white", activebackground="black", width=2)
        btn.grid(row=y, column=x)
        i += 1
        print(' x, y, value : (%s,%s), %s' % (x, y, number))  # output check!

        # likely obsolete code below this comment line.

        if number == "1":
            row1.remove("1")
            col1.remove("1")
        elif number == "2":
            row1.remove("2")
            col1.remove("2")

... snippet ... tk GUI code here ...
```

Comment: If x and y needs to start at 1 then use `for x in range(1, rows+1):` and `for y in range(1, columns+1):`